# Disable focusability of certain entries in TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, treeview

I have a TreeView that is filled with different types of items. The items can either be of type `Node` (then they may have children) or of type `Entry` (then they don't have children). For that, I bound my TreeView to my ViewModel property `AllNodesAndEntries` which is an `ObservableCollection<object>`. For different looks of `Node` and `Entry` I defined two DataTemplates. Here is the code:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding AllNodesAndEntries}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
                                  DataType="{x:Type local:Node}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                       Background="LightBlue"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Entry}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                       Background="LightSalmon"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Now I want to make the `Entry` elements unfocusable if a certain condition is met (that is, if my ViewModel property `MyProp` is `true`).

So I added a trigger into the DataTemplate for `Entry` like this:

```
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Entry}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                       Background="LightSalmon"/>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyProp}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
```

But it does not work, I can still select entries after `MyProp` was set to `true`. **What am I doing wrong? How do I make it work?**

I did put a `NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(MyProp));` in the setter of `MyProp`, so changes to `MyProp` will be reported to the View.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `IsNodeConverter` you've [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39955455/using-path-and-converter-inside-binding),
you can implement a `MultiDataTrigger` that only fires when both conditions are fulfilled:

- ViewModel `MyProp` = true
- TreeViewItem of type `Entry`

**XAML**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:IsNodeConverter x:Key="IsNodeConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

...

    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding AllNodesAndEntries}">
        <TreeView.Resources>

            ...

        </TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition  Binding="{Binding DataContext.MyProp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                        Value="True"/>
                            <Condition  Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IsNodeConverter}}"
                                        Value="False"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"></Setter>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TreeView>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you set the Focusable Property to the DataTemplate which doesn't affect the selection of the TreeViewItem.

Instead you should set it on the TreeViewItem like this:

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyProp}"
                                 Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Focusable"
                                Value="False" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: Correct answer. TextBlock cant be selected normally. When you click TextBlock normally, nothing happens.

Comment: For me it doesn't work either :(  I can still select everything. Also I think even if it did work, it would make all TreeViewItems unselectable, right? I only want the TreeViewItems of type `Entry` to be unselectable.

Comment: I think it doesn't work because the DataContext of the trigger is the `Entry`/`Node` in the TreeViewItem, not the ViewModel. But `MyProp` is defined in the ViewModel, so the binding is not vaild. But how do I change the DataContext of the Trigger/Style? It seems they do not have a DataContext property...

Comment: @Kjara Have a look at ItemContainerStyleSelector and use different style depending on the item type.

Answer (score 0):

It is no problem, you just need to set the `Focusable` property at the TreeViewItem. Just add the following to your `TreeView.Resources`:

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Entry}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Background="LightSalmon"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyProp}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

This style now occurs at all your TreeViewItems. If you like to prevent your `Nodes` from this style you could do it in code behind or just bind your item `object` and use a `Converter`.