# Using Path=. and Converter inside Binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, ivalueconverter

I have trouble defining a trigger for TreeViewItems. I believe it is just some syntax problem, but I don't know what else to write...

This is the Trigger:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=., Converter=IsNodeConverter}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Since it is defined inside `TreeView.ItemContainerStyle`, the `DataContext` should be the contained item itself. The Item can either be of type `Node` or `Entry` and I want to trigger for all Items that are of type `Node`. So I wrote a converter:

```
public class IsNodeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Node)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Which returns `true` if it gets a `Node` as input and `false` otherwise.

But in the part `Binding="{Binding Path=., Converter=IsNodeConverter}"` the compiler complains: "IValueConverter cannot convert from string." (original: "Vom TypeConverter-Objekt für IValueConverter wird das Konvertieren aus einer Zeichenfolge nicht unterstützt.") I don't understand this at all: DataContext is an object of type `Entry` or `Node`, and `Binding Path=.` should keep it that way. **So what is the problem? What string is the compiler talking about? How do I correct this so that the compiler does not complain?**

Here is the full code of the TreeView for reference. The collection ´AllNodesAndEntries´ is an `ObservableCollection<object>` that contains both `Node`s and `Entry`s.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding AllNodesAndEntries}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="{x:Type usrLibVM:Node}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Background="LightBlue"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type usrLibVM:Entry}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Background="LightSalmon"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=., Converter=IsNodeConverter}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your converter is certainly declared in a ResourceDictionary, so it should be referenced as StaticResource:

```
Binding="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource IsNodeConverter}}"
```

or shorter:

```
Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IsNodeConverter}}"
```

Comment: In fact, no. It is not defined in a ResourceDictionary. But thanks to your hint regarding referencing the source, I was able to solve it with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2304330/5333340

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer in thread [Using Value Converters in WPF without having to define them as resources first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2304269/5333340) :

```
<DataTrigger Value="False">
    <DataTrigger.Binding>
        <Binding> <!-- <Binding Path="."> is possible but not necessary -->
            <Binding.Converter>
                <converterNamespace:IsNodeConverter/>
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </DataTrigger.Binding>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
</DataTrigger>
```